# Previous Date getting fetched in pacific time zone in oracle

Tags: oracle, date

In my code when I save one date as todays date in Eastern Time zone, It gets displayed correctly when we view it.But In Pacific time zone, It is showing previous date ie of yesterdays date. We are storing date in Oracle as a date field.

Any special coding required to fecth corect date in Pacific time?

Comment: select to_date(to_char(systimestamp at time zone '6:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual ?

Comment: I have start_date field in DB. How will I retrieve it using above ?

Comment: you insert timestamp with time zone in date field "date" type ? if yes, then you need change timezone before insert like this:  insert into some_table(start_date) values( systimestamp at time zone '6:00' ); - because convert

Comment: The `DATE` data type does not store any time zone information. Thus the problem must be in you application but not at database level.

Answer (score 0):

Dates do not have a time zone - so when you store dates from different time zone you need to make sure that you convert them to be in the same time zone.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name( id INT, value DATE );

INSERT INTO table_name VALUES( 1, TIMESTAMP '2016-07-07 23:00:00 PST' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' );
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES( 1, TIMESTAMP '2016-07-07 23:00:00 EST' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' );
```

Then:

```
SELECT id,
       value AS utc,
       CAST(
         FROM_TZ( CAST( value AS TIMESTAMP ), 'UTC' ) AT TIME ZONE 'EST'
         AS DATE
       ) AS EST,
       CAST(
         FROM_TZ( CAST( value AS TIMESTAMP ), 'UTC' ) AT TIME ZONE 'PST'
         AS DATE
       ) AS PST
FROM   table_name t;
```

Outputs:

```
ID UTC                 EST                 PST
-- ------------------- ------------------- -------------------
 1 2016-07-08 06:00:00 2016-07-08 01:00:00 2016-07-07 23:00:00
 2 2016-07-08 04:00:00 2016-07-07 23:00:00 2016-07-07 21:00:00
```